# How to use a scipy function on each element of a tensor using Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy

I am new to tensorflow, i wish to apply a scipy gamma function to an existing tensor. When I try this

```
from scipy.special import gamma
gamma_t = K.map_fn(lambda x:gamma(1.0 + 1.0 / x) ,b)
```

Where b is an existing tensor I get

```
TypeError: ufunc 'gamma' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

How Can I solve This?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use SciPy functions (or NumPy based functions, in general) directly on a TensorFlow tensor. You could do it with [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), but in general the best option is to use TensorFlow operations only. In this case, neither the Keras backend abstraction nor TensorFlow have the gamma function, but TensorFlow has [`tf.lgamma`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lgamma), which is its logarithm (well, the logarithm of its absolute value, to be precise). You can then get what you want with:

```
gamma_t = K.map_fn(lambda x: K.exp(tf.lgamma(1.0 + 1.0 / x)), b)
```

PS: Note that generally it is recommended to use only [backend functions](https://keras.io/backend/) when manipulating Keras tensors, but since this is a rather specific feature and it is not exposed there (also, although Theano does have a gamma function implementation, CNTK currently does not, so it would not be possible to implement it for all backends).